# random test log generator

Tags: text-processing, random

I need to write a script to create random test log data.

Log data should be delimited with "|"(pipe) and 10,000 lines with 500 bytes, and each line and contain following format with random data.

```
date|time|pid|status|data|comment
```

range of each column:

```
date    : 20130101
time    : 09:00:00-11:59:59
pid     : 3000-5000
status  : OK || TEMP || PERM
data    : refer words/sentences used in whichever of the following pages and set them randomly - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3
comment : fill in with "X" to fit one line as 500 bytes.
```

(Example) random test log data would be like below:

```
20120101|09:00:00|4887|TEMP|Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service) is an online file storage web service offered by Amazon Web Services. Amazon S3 provides storage through web services interfaces (REST, SOAP, and BitTorrent).[1] Amazon launched S3, its first publicly available web service, in the United States in March 2006[2] and in Europe in November 2007.[3]|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
20120101|09:00:00|4418|TEMP|At its inception, Amazon charged end users US$0.15 per gigabyte-month, with additional charges for bandwidth used in sending and receiving data, and a per-request (get or put) charge.[4] On November 1, 2008, pricing moved to tiers where end users storing more than 50 terabytes receive discounted pricing.[5] Amazon says that S3 uses the same scalable storage infrastructure that Amazon.com uses to run its own global e-commerce network.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
20120101|09:00:01|4124|PERM|Amazon S3 is reported to store more than 2 trillion objects as of April 2013.[7] This is up from 102 billion objects as of March 2010,[8] 64 billion objects in August 2009,[9] 52 billion in March 2009,[10] 29 billion in October 2008,[5] 14 billion in January 2008, and 10 billion in October 2007.[11]|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
20120101|09:00:02|3977|OK|S3 uses include web hosting, image hosting, and storage for backup systems. S3 guarantees 99.9% monthly uptime service-level agreement (SLA),[12] that is, not more than 43 minutes of downtime per month.[13]|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
20120101|09:00:02|4020|OK|Details of S3's design are not made public by Amazon, though it clearly manages data with an object storage architecture. According to Amazon, S3's design aims to provide scalability, high availability, and low latency at commodity costs.|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: This smells a lot like homework... what have you tried on your own, where are you stuck? Did you do anything yet or are you just waiting for us to provide the finished script for you?

Comment: Why does the range specify 20130101 but the sample data uses 20120101?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple shell script that you could easily extend for further variations in the data.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
hash='####################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################'

while [ "$count" -lt 10000 ]
do
  case $((RANDOM % 3)) in
        (0) status=OK
                ;;
        (1) status=TEMP
                ;;
        (2) status=PERM
                ;;
  esac

  case $((RANDOM % 4)) in
        (0) data=\
'Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service) is an online file storage web service offered by Amazon Web Services. Amazon S3 provides storage through web services interfaces (REST, SOAP, and BitTorrent).[1] Amazon launched S3, its first publicly available web service, in the United States in March 2006[2] and in Europe in November 2007.[3]'
                ;;
        (1) data=\
'Amazon S3 is reported to store more than 2 trillion objects as of April 2013.[7] This is up from 102 billion objects as of March 2010,[8] 64 billion objects in August 2009,[9] 52 billion in March 2009,[10] 29 billion in October 2008,[5] 14 billion in January 2008, and 10 billion in October 2007.[11]'
                ;;
        (2) data=\
'S3 uses include web hosting, image hosting, and storage for backup systems. S3 guarantees 99.9% monthly uptime service-level agreement (SLA),[12] that is, not more than 43 minutes of downtime per month.[13]'
                ;;
        (3) data=\
'Details of S3'\''s design are not made public by Amazon, though it clearly manages data with an object storage architecture. According to Amazon, S3'\''s design aims to provide scalability, high availability, and low latency at commodity costs.'
                ;;
  esac

  part=$(
    printf '%s|%s|%d|%s|%s' \
        "20130101" \
        $(printf '%02d:%02d:%02d' $((RANDOM % 3 + 9)) $((RANDOM % 60)) $((RANDOM % 60)) ) \
        $((RANDOM % 2000 + 3000)) \
        "$status" \
        "$data"
    )
  printf '%.500s\n' "$part"'|'"$hash"
  count=$((count + 1))
done
```

The `count` variable gets us 10,000 runs through the loop. The `hash` variable is a mask of sorts; we use it to pad the final string to 500 characters (the value is 500 hash marks, produced with [this idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492630/117549): `printf %500s | tr " " "#"`).

The two `case` statements inside the loop select pseudorandom strings from the sample data; this is where you could extend the `data` section for more options there.

The `part` variable assignment uses `printf` to assemble the first five fields: the static date string, a pseudorandom timestamp between 9:00 and 11:59:59, a pseudorandom pid, the selected status code, and the selected data string.

We then ask printf to print a concatenated string of:

- the above `part` string
- a `|` delimiter, and
- the `hash` marks from above

... the entire printed string is then cut off at 500 characters with the `.500` [format width specifier](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).